# Pandas sample by filter criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like the one below

```
d = {'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'var2': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'class': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    var1   var2  class
0     1     5      a
1     2     6      a
2     3     7      c
3     4     8      b
```

I would like to be able to change the proportion of the class column. For example I would like to down-sample at random the `a` class by 50% but keep the number of rows for the other classes the same. the results would be:

```
df
    var1   var2  class
0     1     5      a
1     3     7      c
2     4     8      b
```

How would this be done.

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach to split the DataFrame into `df_selection` and `df_remaining` first.
I then reduced `df_selection` by `REMOVE_PERCENTAGE` and merged the resulting DataFrame with `df_remaining` again.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'var2': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'class': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

REMOVE_PERCENTAGE = 0.5  # between 0 and 1

df = df.set_index(['class'])

df_selection = df.loc['a'] \
    .reset_index()
df_remaining = df.drop('a') \
    .reset_index()

rows_to_remove = int(REMOVE_PERCENTAGE * len(df_selection.index))
drop_indices = np.random.choice(df_selection.index, rows_to_remove, replace=False)
df_selection_reduced = df_selection.drop(drop_indices)

df_result = pd.concat([df_selection_reduced, df_remaining]) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_result)
```